# Ruby on Rails: Delete link causing nameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

I am new to rails and I am following a tutorial. I have the same code but I am getting a NameError when I include a "Delete" link in my view.

Here is the error

```
NameError in Posts#index
undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x3a0c9b0>:0x3a0a220>
```

Here is the code

```
<h1>Blog Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<h3><%= link_to post.title,post %></h3>
<p><%= post.body %></p>
<hr>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", :method => :delete %>
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h3><%= link_to post.title,post %></h3>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
    <hr>
   <%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this post?' } %>

    <% end %>
```

Edit More info. Your delete link needs to inside the loop or block.

Comment: The problem, incidentally, is that after you close the block (with `end`), the `post` variable is no longer defined.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `link_to` code to this one:

```
<h3><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h3>
```

and this one too:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", :method => :delete %>
```

`link_to` needs a URL as the second parameter.

If you got other error, please make sure that you have next line in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
```